# My JTable does not expand to full width of panel it is in

Tags: java, swing, jtable, size

how can I make my JTable use the full available with of the parent panel? I've tried to work with setSize or setPreferredSize but that didn't work. The latter actually produced a very tiny version of the table.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 25, 15); 
String[] columnNames = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
        Object[][] data = new Object[20][columnNames.length];
        for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ){
            data[i] = new Object[]{"Some other stuff that is long", "K", "1234567891011121314", "R", "T"};
        }

        JTable skillTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        skillTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true );
        JScrollPane scrollTable = new JScrollPane(skillTable);
        constraints.fill = constraints.HORIZONTAL;
        panel.add(scrollTable, constraints);
```

This is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4b6A.png

Comment: Do you need to use a `GridBagLayout`? Why not just use a `GridLayout`? Doing `new GridLayout()` will cause the table to take up the entire panel.

Comment: What other components are being added to panel? Can you just simply use a BorderLayout and place the scrollTable in CENTER?

Comment: There will only be another button in the panel. I think I will go with an extra panel for the table using GridLayout. Thanks for your help.

Comment: GridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;, but to use JScrollPane with BorderLayout for JPanel

Comment: I also tried horizontal but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) Neat and Simple

```
 JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    String[] columnNames = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
    Object[][] data = new Object[20][columnNames.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        data[i] = new Object[]{"Some other stuff that is long", "K", "1234567891011121314", "R", "T"};
    }

    JTable skillTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    skillTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    JScrollPane scrollTable = new JScrollPane(skillTable);
    panel.add(scrollTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //as you said you want to add a button as well
    JPanel buttonpanel=new JPanel();
    buttonpanel.add(new JButton("Test"));
    panel.add(buttonpanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!